# R: Vectorize for loop with interdependent values

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, vector

I simulate a warehouse in R, where supplies (o.in) arrive with random lead times and demand (d) is served. The stock level (stockHistory) is calculated based on the difference between supply and demand.

```
for(i in 1:periods){

  stockHistory[i] = stockHistory[i] - d[i] + o.in[i] # o.in has been determined in previous looping, d is known before loop
  openOrders = openOrders - o.in[i]

  missing_packages = ceiling((reorderPoint - stockHistory[i] - openOrders)/q) # stockHistory + openOrders are based on o.in and calculated in loop

  if (missing_packages > 0 ) {
    openOrders = openOrders + missing_packages * q
    o.in[leadtimes[i]+i] = o.in[leadtimes[i]+i] + missing_packages * q # leadtimes is known before looping
  }
}
```

How can I avoid the *for loop* by vectorization? My problem is that I do not know how to handle the

```
o.in[leadtimes[i]+i] = o.in[leadtimes[i]+i] + missing_packages * q
```

in a vectorizedd way so that the offset *leadtimes[i]+i* in the vector is accounted for elementwise in the calculation. I checked diff(), but it doesn't seem apt for my use case.

The second problem is that I cannot determine the right order for the operations since they are based one on another.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sample input and output (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be quite helpful here to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at it line by line.  For example:

```
 stockHistory[i] = stockHistory[i] - d[i] + o.in[i]
```

Since there's no "history dependence," just write

```
stockHistory <- stockHistory -d +o.in 

  openOrders = openOrders - o.in[i]
```

Here, make `openOrders` a vector of same length as everything else.

```
openOrders <- -o.in # and later modify each i-th element in some way
```

The problem you're going to have with `missing_packages` is that you don't appear to have made it a vector of values which align with your i-th time periods.  When you've better defined your situation I can suggest further vectorized code. I will point out that  your current setup is naive, since adding zero doesn't change a value :-) .  To point:

```
if ( foo > 0 )  bar <- bar + 5*foo
```

is a waste of effort.  `bar<-bar + 5*foo`  does exactly the same thing whether `foo` is zero or not.

Comment: My problem is the order of calculations. I guess, the vectorization approach you suggest would probably lead to:

    stockHistory <- stockHistory -d +o.in 
    openOrders = openOrders - o.in
 missing_packages = ceiling((reorderPoint - stockHistory[i] - openOrders)/q)
    openOrders = openOrders + missing_packages * q
    o.in[leadtimes] = o.in[leadtimes] + missing_packages * q  # does this approach work with the indices?

Now, my problem is, that the sequence of operations is flawed, since I would need the o.in before I calculate it. Do you see, what I mean?

Comment: Sadly, not in the least, because you're still claiming `openOrders` is a scalar, which means you can calculate all i-th instances vectorially.